# In what order does the Java Security manager evaluate and apply permissions?

Tags: java, security

I am trying to find out, in which order and how far the Java Security manager evaluates the grant { ... } clauses.
If, say, I want to grant some downloaded piece of code to read **and write** from/into a **particular** subdirectory `(.../X/Y/Z`) of the user's home directory, while all other code can read (but not write) up to 2 levels higher (i.e. subdirectory `.../X` and below of the user's home directory).

How can I specify that? Would a sequence like the following be correct?

```
... 
grant codebase http://foo.bar.com/test.jar {
   permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.dir}/X/Y/Z/*", "read,write"; }; 
...
grant {
   permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.dir}/X/-", "read"; };
...
```

i.e. would the security evaluation for code downloaded as part of `test.jar` file stop after the first grant clause (and thus **not** grant read-access to, say, directory `.../X/Y`)?

And can I be sure with the above settings, that **no** piece of code of the current application will get access higher up, i.e. into the user's home-directory itself (or even higher..)?

Answer (score 0):

Classes are given the entire **set** of applicable permissions. Order isn't really meaningful here.

Answer (score 0):

You can print out the order in which policies are applied (and sometimes augmented) by providing the following JVM arguments:

> -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.debug=all

I would post a sample output, but it turns out the console output is very, very long.

- to directly answer your question about the order of evaluation, I would assume that it is implementation defined, as I have never been able to find authoritative documentation on the system specifics.
- As for guaranteeing that the user home directory cannot be accessed, it is impossible to say without seeing all of the policy files that are loaded (including the one bundled with the JRE installation, and the one in user.home if they exist).

Good luck!